Определить зависимость слова в предложениях
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в предложении "Названия полимеров образуются из названия мономера с приставкой поли." от какого слова зависит выражение выражение «с приставкой»?
Также интересно было бы узнать в предложении "Объектами изучения науки являются биополимеры." выражение "объектами изучения" выступает как целая конструкция? От какого слова зависит?
Спасибо

Названия - это несамостоятельное слово, - названия какие или чьи? - полимерные, полимеров. Поэтому имеет место быть выражение "название полимеров" - два слова находятся во взаимной зависимости и всё выражение является подлежащим, оно не делится на "названия" и "полимеров". Это как в случае с предлогом: вынуть из банку -  вынуть откуда или как? вынуть "из",  - из чего? из банки? - а от предлога вопрос не задашь. к банке.)

@Буратино, Система понятий и категорий современной грамматики. Выражение "Система категорий и понятий" из того же разряда?

Скорее всего слова "категория" и "система" это слова такого же рода. Но вы должны понимать, что то, что я написал, это ересь, это не школьная грамматика и не факт, что институтская, хотя, если я найду работу, где подобное рассматривается, я попробую вас сообщить. Я просто сам столкнулся с подобным, не далее как вчера. Когда возник вопрос слово "группа" - это существительное или нет. Я так думаю, что нет. А если оно употребляется без указания какая или чья группа, то это современный сленг, а не русский язык. В лит. ист. "группа" встречается только в выражениях в связке с определяющим словом

В английском языке есть категория называется Compound Nouns - то есть "составные понятия" смысл которых в связке слов, а не в словах по отдельности. Но может есть понимание, что тут происходит с точки зрения русской грамматики?

Предложения содержат грамматические и стилистические ошибки.

Названия полимеров образуются из названия мономера с приставкой поли.

Грамматическая ошибка. Правильно:
Названия полимеров образуются от названия соответствующего мономера с помощью приставки поли.

Объектами изучения науки являются биополимеры.

Стилистическая неточность. Два родительных падежа подряд, смысл неясный.  Два Р.п. в общем случае не запрещены, но здесь непонятно, что изучают: науку или объект.
Редактирование:
Объектами научного изучения являются биополимеры.
Объектами изучения в науке являются биополимеры.
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ

Современный сленг в грамматике? Да, похоже. Вот и Розенталь говорит:

Розенталь §204. Нанизывание одинаковых форм
Затрудняет понимание текста скопление одинаковых падежных 
форм. Чаще всего встречается нанизывание форм родительного 
падежа, например: «В целях лучшей постановки дела повышения 
уровня жизни...»; «Для решения задачи ускорения подъема 
уровня сельского хозяйства...»; «Для выполнения требования 
устранения отставания производства деталей намечены 
конкретные меры».


Уж сколько раз твердили миру...

Ещё раз о нанизывании родительных падежей
Работа с нормами управления на уроках русского языка
"Классификация грамматических ошибок" (11 класс)
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Обзор темы.  Что такое словосочетания и как распознавать связи между ними

Предлоги

Словарь Д.Э. Розенталь "Управление в русском языке"

Розенталь, Стилистика. Управление. https://evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm



Предложение взял изи Википедии). Если не сложно, подскажите, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь материалы, которые научат определять зависимость одного слова от другого. Вот например в предложении « Предложные конструкции характеризуются большей степенью сочетаемости с названиями средств механического транспорта» выражение с названиями зависит от какого слова? Спасибо

Я добавила ссылки на некоторые материалы в ответ. Предложные конструкции характеризуются (чем?) большей степенью (чего?) сочетаемости (с чем?) с названиями (чего?) средств (чего?) механического транспорта».

спасибо большое

Посмотрите еще этот учебник. Он для педвузов, но материал изложен доступно. Возможно, он будет вам полезен : стр.9 и дальше  https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf

"Названия полимеров образуются из названия мономера с приставкой поли." - названия какого? - с приставкой. Тут есть сомнения связанные с согласованием числа - полимеров-мономера. Лучше, если будет всё в единственном числе. "Название полимера образуется из названия мономера с приставкой поли."
"Объектами изучения науки являются биополимеры." - я думаю, тут нужно писать не объектами, а "объектом" - "Объектом изучения науки являются биополимеры."Объект изучаения" или "объект науки" тут выражение, которое не делится и выступает как целостная конструкция, скорее всего, потому что пропущен прелог "объект для изучения" или а "объект науки" - это устойчивое выражение(поэтому не объектЫ), и, кстати, тут не ясно к какому слову относится слово объект, поэтому возникает подобная беспредложная конструкция "объект изучения (и) науки".
То есть вся конструкция содержит три слова "объект изучения науки" и она не делится.
Если бы было "изучаемый объект" - то слово "объект" было бы главным и самостоятельным.
Кстати говоря. Выбор единственного и множественного, когда речь идет об обобщении, падает на единственное число, поэтому человек - а не человекИ(которое вообще не корректно), а если нужно группу людей указать говорят - люди, а если речь идет о массе людей - народ. А вот слово "народы" будет иметь совсем другой смысл. Поэтому в документах пишут "многонациональный народ", а не "многонациональные народы". То есть это даже не про число, а про понятие. Понятие - это слово в единственном числе.
Все правила постулируются через понятия.
А вот лозунги, наоборот, обещая, могут использовать формы множественного числа: землю - крестьянам!(а не "крестьянин - владелец земли")
А вот когда речь заходит о конкретном случае, а не общем, тогда появляется число, указывающее на непосредственные обстоятельства дела. И появление множественного числа обусловлено частным случаем, а не общим правилом.
